Array Enum From C# to PostgreSQL
all type and table names are simplified
i use c# and npgsql
in postgres there is a table that has the type anyType[]
and there is the custom type itself
create type anyType AS enum ('A', 'B');

create table partners(
anys anyType[]
);

I can't do an insert into a table from c# code and I can't read it.
This is an array of enums, I have exactly the same enum in the code, with the same parameters.
    public enum anyType
    {
        A,
        B
    }

from sql i can do insert:
insert into AnyTable values(ARRAY['A', 'B']::auth_method[], );

from c#
const string sql = $"insert into {TableName} ({anyType}) values (@any)";
await using var connection = await dataSource.OpenConnectionAsync(cancellationToken);
await using var command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("any", entity.AnyType);
var affected = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancellationToken);
return affected == 1;

I did this too
After this failed, it adds a value only if I try to insert an empty array, but if I insert a value it says that there is no such type
builder.MapEnum<anyType>("anyType");
builder.MapComposite<anyType>("anyType");


While databases do support this, putting structured data like arrays in a column is usually poor schema design, where you should have an additional table instead.

But also, the AddWithValue() line is certainly wrong in two different ways, since 1) you're giving a type for the 2nd argument, when you should give a value, and 2) the input is expecting an array instead of a single value. And I don't actually know what postgresql needs to map to that kind of type (so this is just a comment), but to get started at least you should construct an array of anyType enum values and pass in that array, even if the array only has one item. I also saw an example passing arrays here: https://www.codeguru.com/dotnet/postgres-tricks-in-net/

The Basic type mapping docs show that array values should be passed as T[] or List<T> objects in parameters whose type is Array | NpgsqlDbType. The final note is To construct the NpgsqlDbType for an int[], write NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Integer.. You'll have to either construct the parameter explicitly or use an AddWithValue overload that allows you to specify the NpgsqlDbType
